# Img srcset loading images when browser at half image size

Tags: html, srcset

(*using latest version of Firefox*)

I have my `img` written like so:

```
<body>
    <script>
        function imageLoaded(img) {
            console.log('the responsive image is loaded');
            img.className += ' loaded';
        }
    </script>

    <img class="backgroundImage"
         onload="imageLoaded(this)"
         src="assets/water_bg_1920.jpg"
         sizes="100vw"
         srcset="assets/water_bg_2560.jpg 2560w,
                 assets/water_bg_1920.jpg 1920w,
                 assets/water_bg_1024.jpg 1024w"/>
</body>
```

and my css—

```
@keyframes fadeIn
  0%
    opacity: 0
  100%
    opacity: 1

.backgroundImage
  opacity: 0

.loaded
  opacity: 1
  animation: fadeIn 3s
```

When my browser is at `960px`, it loads the `1920` image. At `512px` it loads the `1024` image. Anything higher and it loads the `2560` image.

I'm very confused as to exactly *how* it's deciding to load these images at these widths when I have `sizes` set to `100vw`. Shouldn't it be using the `1024` image until the browser width is `1024px`, the `1920` image when the browser width is from `1024px - 1920px` and the 2560 img for anything higher? Am I misunderstanding something here?

**edit:** the behavior is also occurring in latest version of Chrome, except in addition to the original problem it's loading the `2560` image in *addition* to the smaller image— every time!

**edit2:** latest version of Safari is behaving the same as Firefox.

**edit3:** found a [fiddle](http://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/hFxyj/) made by someone else testing. it behaves the same way (*does not use the smaller image until the browser width is 50% of the image size*). is this a bug? or an intended feature of `srcset` & `sizes`?

Comment: Need to see the code for this function: `imageLoaded(this)` and possibly the CSS for `.backgroundImage` as well.

Comment: I edited the original post. Sorry, I didn't think they were relevant.

Comment: No worries, I think it's the function that's probably throwing you off, let's see...

Comment: You are right, the JS is irrelevant. I h8 Firefox it used to be a good browser. I'm glad you figured it out. Happy coding.:)

Comment: No no, I didn't figure it out! The behavior is even worse in Chrome lmao. I edited my original post for more clarification.

Comment: My bad, derp  >.< I was going to say `sizes` does it's own math and determines which image to use. It's calculations include the device width which is different than viewport or screen-width, screen pixel density etc. Also I think the order of the images matter too so try reversing the order.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, well the solution that worked for me (*which has approximately the same support with the exception of one older Safari version*) is to use the `<picture>` tag like so:

```
<picture class="backgroundContainer">
    <source srcset="assets/water_bg_1024.jpg" media="(min-width: 0px) and (max-width:1024px)">
    <source srcset="assets/water_bg_1920.jpg" media="(min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1920px)">
    <source srcset="assets/water_bg_2560.jpg" media="(min-width: 1921px)">
    <img class="backgroundImage" onload="imageLoaded(this)" src="assets/water_bg_1920.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

Which loads all of the images correctly at the right breakpoints on all latest versions of browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I got to work more sanely, with a media query and a length set on the `sizes`. I see the img breakout to 2560w on my iPhone, but that's because of pixel-density of retina. To get the breakpoints hitting tighter, you'll need to add more media queries.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>sizes</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x576/000/fff?text=1024w" sizes="(min-width: 36em) 33.3vw, 100vw" srcset="http://placehold.it/2560x1280/00f/fc0?text=2560w 2560w, http://placehold.it/1920x1080/e00/fcf?text=1920w 1920w, http://placehold.it/1024x576/000/fff?text=1024w 1024w" />
</body>

</html>
```